# C# linear function, array of decimals with null

Tags: c#, function, decimal

How to write in C # a linear function, which from the database table field values = decimal (10,2) null

e.g.

```
{10,00; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; 12.00}
```

I will get:

```
{10; 10.25; 10.50; 10.75; 11.00; 11.25; 11.50; 11.75; 12,00}.
```

The size of the array and the number of 'null' element are unknown.

Only first and last elements are known. In this example, 10,00 and 12,00.

Comment: How do you get the numerical and null values? Where do you store them?

Comment: Any chance that you could write "which from the database table field values = decimal (10,2) null" in a simpler form of English?

Comment: "*The size of the array and the number of `null` element are unknown*" - without this info, it is impossible to do what you want to. I mean if all info you have is `10` and `2` how could one possibly *guess* the step and the number of final values?

Comment: "Only first and last elements are known. In this example, 10,00 and 12,00." And hopefully the stepsize, isn´t it? Anyway we´re not doing your job. Write what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: `delta = (last - first) / (length - 1)`; here we have `delta = (12.00-10) / (9 - 1) = 0.25`; so `[10, 10+delta, 10+2*delta,...,12.00]`

Comment: What happens if the database values are not `null` anywhere else? Is that a possibility and should it yield a different output? If not, why are those `null`s there in the first place, when your input requires only two numbers and a count? Interpolating values in the entire sequence (with known values inbetween) is not the same problem as interpolating between first and last, ignoring all the rest.

Comment: Note also that if the intent is to somehow write this sequence back to the database, you'll need to be able to correlate the rows to their original order (either because there's an unmentioned key column of some kind, or because you're going to store them in ascending order). Tables in databases are just sets (unlike arrays in C#, which have a strict linear order), and there'd be no way to distinguish "the third `null`" from "the fourth `null`" without such data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk the array and add the step each time:

```
var array = new double?[]{10.00, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 12.00};

var step = (array.Last() - array.First()) / (array.Length - 1);
for (var i = 1; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    array[i] =  array[i - 1] + step;
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LHkcwL)

Also, you can use Linq like this:

```
var result = array.Select((x, i) => array[0] + step * i);
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mCor5c)

Comment: You needlessly compute a step size (`step`) that will be the same on each iteration. (And note that working on a fixed step size may mean you accumulate errors)

Comment: I'd go back to using `.First()` & `.Last()` - for arrays these are optimized to using indexing and they are far more readable.

Comment: Do nothing if `array.Length <= 1`: we don't want exception on `.../ (array.Length - 1);`

Comment: @Rafalon: technically, we can have an array with one item only - first one and the same item is the last. If we are given `[12.00]` array we have no items with `null` to fill and thus can do nothing (instead of `DivideByZeroException`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko by the time I posted my comment, you edited yours, and what I understood from it changed radically, that's why I deleted mine

Comment: There is nothing to do if array length is 2 either - you have start & end point & nothing to fill in.

Comment: Did you reject my edit to the link? Because its still wrong, the last two steps are 11.5 and 12 which is 0.5 instead of 0.25.

Comment: @horotab yes because your fix is wrong too. I updated. Thank you btw.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever A solution without the `step` could be `var maxI = array.Length - 1;
for (var i = 1; i < maxI; i++)
{
array[i] = array.Last() * i / maxI + array.First() * (maxI - i) / maxI;
}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNSwMxEL3nVww9JW43dr2u4qEgKBUEDx7aHtI0toE0wUy2WMr@9nWSXdCjl0nyviY8jbVGPQwdWn@A9wsmc2rZ35dcWf/VMoZJJatBO4UIb@zKACboHOweXpX1XBCYCYB96HbOPK63oGJUF3iAKzQLuZiD75z732zusr6n3TnxrCKc1PczRZVIuTL@kI5QQ9MWwWeIwLPKkqRp6bgvBrpVlSiS8W8wBqzt9jdLYeICbsh0O26pJubJxoniBa/Bikkzru3LXAaPwRn5EW0y1JjhmCKVKF8C9TLbxI2fzcdIIbKxZ/0w/AA "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")